# Run time error - 2147220973 (80040213) The transport failed to connect to the server while sending mail from vb6

Tags: vb.net, email-attachments

I am making one application in vb6 which sends mail from an application, it gives me

> Run time error - 2147220973 (80040213) The transport failed to contact
>   to the server

, I did all the given solution gives before

Please help if any one knows solution.

Code:
code:

```
{
mStrProcName = "MonthlyXlMail_EmployeePerformance"
sFilePath = (App.Path & "\TimeTaken.xls")
  iConf.Load -1

Set Flds = iConf.Fields
Set lobj_cdomsg = New CDO.Message

lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = Trim(rsMail!ServerUrl)
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort) = CInt(Trim(rsMail!Port))
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = IIf(rsMail!ReqSSL = "Y", True, False)

lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUserName) = Trim(rsMail!EMailID)
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendPassword) = Trim(rsMail!EmailPassword)
                        lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 30

lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Update

lobj_cdomsg.To = Trim(strMail)

lobj_cdomsg.From = Trim(rsMail!EMailID)

lobj_cdomsg.Subject = IIf(Len(Trim(txtsubject.Text)) = 0, "Performance Report", Trim(txtsubject.Text))

lobj_cdomsg.TextBody = IIf(Len(Trim(txtDescription.Text)) = 0, "Find Attachment", Trim(txtDescription.Text))

'lobj_cdomsg.HTMLBody = strMsg
lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment (sFilePath)

lobj_cdomsg.Send
}
```

Comment: i am afraid,you will not get any help without providing more details like what have u done,some code snippets etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gmail with Two factor auth? This also prevents using smtp with basic authentication.

Create a custom app in you Gmail security settings to add a new password for your messaging application.

```
1. Login into your Gmail account
2. Goto https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
3. Choose 'Custom' app.
4. Typ 'Gmail Smtp', or something
5. Click 'Generate'
6. It will give you a password token.
```

Use this token as your password in your messaging application instead of your own password.

Comment: Yes i have anti virus but already i stop it and yes mail server and port number is also correct

Comment: Have you tried telnet using command prompt to ensure your computer/server can connect to the mailserver? What is the response of the mailserver?

Comment: It gives me => 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Try to install from Control Panel, Program and Features, install Telnet Client.

Comment: Okay.. tried your code without sending an attachment?

Comment: still same issue, please help

Comment: Are you using authentication to connect to the smtp server?

Comment: Can you temoporary disable auth? Have you tried an smtp server without auth?

Comment: No I haven't tried without auth because auth is bit compulsory for me.

Comment: And are you using Ssl or not? Tried without ssl?

Comment: I tried with both, but still same error, I don't know what's the issue but error is not resolved

Comment: Are you using Gmail as Smtp server?

Comment: Yes, I am using Gmail as server,

Comment: And you are using Two factor auth? See my answer above. (edited)

Comment: I really don't understand what you trying to tell to do, what is the effect of it?

Comment: You cannot connect smtp if you have Two factor authentication activated on your account.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting, I discovered that turning off the VPN and adjusting regional settings resolved the issue.